# Dynamic tree with PHP and jTree

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, web-services

I'm trying to find another solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958188/dynamic-tree-view-with-php)

I tryed to use jSon Tree library to encode my associative array but for some reason the result jSon is malformed, I don't know what to do... my PHP code is below.

```
<?php
$trenino = array();

foreach ($hTwo as $k => $html_val) {
  if ($k < 2) continue;

  $new_string = explode('|',$html_val->nodeValue);

  $padre = $new_string[0]; //echo '<p>padre: '.$padre.'</p>';
  $figlio = $new_string[1]; //echo '<p>figlio: '.$figlio.'</p>';
  $desc = $new_string[2]; //echo '<p>desc: '.$desc.'</p>';
  $colore = $new_string[3]; //echo '<p>colore: '.$colore.'</p>';
  $lt = $new_string[4]; //echo '<p>lt: '.$lt.'</p>';
  $pallino = $new_string[5];
  $magazz = $new_string[6]; //echo 'magazzino: '.$magazz;

  $trenino['parent'][] = $new_string[0];
  $trenino['id'][] =  $new_string[1];
  $trenino['name'][] =  $new_string[2];
  $trenino['colore'][] = $new_string[3];
  $trenino['lt'][] = $new_string[4];
  $trenino['pallino'][] = $new_string[5];
  $trenino['magazz'][] = $new_string[6];

echo json_encode($trenino);
?>
```

this is part of my json result:

```
{"parent":[""],"id":["MY00027770096"],"name":["REJANE 85MM BOTTONE E CHIAVE "],"colore":["50FF15"],"lt":["0"],"pallino":[""],"magazz":["NP"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter to your code to group all of your information into one.

```
<?php
$trenino = array();
$count = 0;

foreach ($hTwo as $k => $html_val) {
  if ($k < 2) continue;

  $new_string = explode('|',$html_val->nodeValue);

  $padre = $new_string[0]; //echo '<p>padre: '.$padre.'</p>';
  $figlio = $new_string[1]; //echo '<p>figlio: '.$figlio.'</p>';
  $desc = $new_string[2]; //echo '<p>desc: '.$desc.'</p>';
  $colore = $new_string[3]; //echo '<p>colore: '.$colore.'</p>';
  $lt = $new_string[4]; //echo '<p>lt: '.$lt.'</p>';
  $pallino = $new_string[5];
  $magazz = $new_string[6]; //echo 'magazzino: '.$magazz;

  $trenino[$count]['parent'] = $new_string[0];
  $trenino[$count]['id'][] =  $new_string[1];
  $trenino[$count]['name'][] =  $new_string[2];
  $trenino[$count]['colore'][] = $new_string[3];
  $trenino[$count]['lt'][] = $new_string[4];
  $trenino[$count]['pallino'][] = $new_string[5];
  $trenino[$count]['magazz'][] = $new_string[6];
  $count++;

echo json_encode($trenino);
?>
```

Edit as per comments:

Visual (output from [Makiweb](https://makitweb.com/create-treeview-with-jstree-plugin-and-php/) example):

[image]

Visual (actual):

[image]

The difference is that they are grouped together by that first number `[0]`, `[1]`, etc in the expectation. Adding the `$count` variable in front will generate that for you.

Comment: `{"parent":["","MY00027770096","MY0002_0096_777_I01"],"id":["MY00027770096","MY0002_0096_777_I01","355-0676-221"],"name":["REJANE 85MM BOTTONE E CHIAVE ","REJANE 85MM BOTTONE E CHIAVE","PELLICOLA C\/PIASTRA AGGANCIATU"],"colore":["50FF15","FFC911","4274F4"],"lt":["0","0","0"],"pallino":["","",""],"magazz":["NP","NP1","NP91Q"]}`

Comment: The information is allready grouped in $trenino array, the problem is that when i call json_encode($trenino); the jSon result is not the same as here in this tutorial [link](https://makitweb.com/create-treeview-with-jstree-plugin-and-php/) and jTree doesnt load anything... The resulting jSon for me its like this one above ...

Comment: I've updated my answer. You will still need to add the `$count` in there to group them by number, not by individual element.

Comment: Following up. How did you make out?

Comment: hey Hello my friend just take a look below in my answer, and hope not to be too pushy, I just wanted to ask you one more thing... Did you ever worked with this Kind of tree library [here](https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/) i did not quite understand how to set up that library...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I've made it another way since i need the real ids from my jSon data. I've dinamically build up a string modifying the assciative array and then manipulated my string to obtain a correct jSon data string to let jsTree read from that. Take a look!

```
<?php
$trenino = array();

$custom_attr ='';
$json_string = '';

foreach ($hTwo as $k => $html_val) {
  if ($k < 2) continue;
  //echo $html_val->nodeValue;
  $new_string = explode('|',$html_val->nodeValue);

  $padre = $new_string[0]; //echo '<p>padre: '.$padre.'</p>';
  $figlio = $new_string[1]; //echo '<p>figlio: '.$figlio.'</p>';
  $desc = $new_string[2]; //echo '<p>desc: '.$desc.'</p>';
  $colore = $new_string[3]; //echo '<p>colore: '.$colore.'</p>';
  $lt = $new_string[4]; //echo '<p>lt: '.$lt.'</p>';
  $pallino = $new_string[5];
  $magazz = $new_string[6]; //echo 'magazzino: '.$magazz;

  $trenino['id'] =  $new_string[1];
  $trenino['parent'] = $new_string[0];

  $custom_attr =  '<span class="itmref">'.$new_string[1].'</span> <span class="itmdes">'.$new_string[2].'</span><span class="hide colore">'.$new_string[3].'</span><span class="lt">'.$new_string[4].' gg</span><span class="hide pallino">'.$new_string[5].'</span><span class="hide magazz">'.$new_string[6];
  $trenino['text'] = $custom_attr;



  $json_string .= json_encode($trenino);


}

//echo '<pre>',print_r($trenino),'</pre>';

/*
foreach($trenino as $special_item) {
    echo '<p>'; var_dump($special_item); '</p>';
}*/

$json_string = '['.$json_string.']';

$json_string = str_replace('"parent":"",','"parent":"#",',$json_string);
$json_string = str_replace('}{','},{',$json_string);

?>
```